# how to redirect a link to another link using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i have a link like:

```
www.website.com/index.php?id=123456
```

and i want to redirect to:

```
www.website.com/test.php
```

the problem is that the `id` can be different each time, could be `id=123456` or `id=632456`

any ideas on how to solve this?

thanks

edit:

what if i want to redirect it to `www.website.com/test.php?id=123456` or whatever that id is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteRule index\.php.* test.php
```

Or you can be more specific:

```
RewriteRule index\.php\?id=[0-9]+$ test.php
```

Or you can even send the id too:

```
RewriteRule index\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ test.php?id=$1
```

Comment: thanks, what if i want to redirect it to `www.website.com/test.php?id=123456` or whatever that id is?  sorry to pop with another question